# Получить абсолютный путь к картинкам (Android)

Tags: android, java

Не подскажите как получить абсолютные пути к файлам, которые расположены в папке assets/images ?

Answer (score 4):

А зачем Вам абсолютный путь? AssetManager сам найдет файл. Вы просто передаете ему имя:

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getResources().getAssets();
InputStream  stream = assetManager.open(Constants.IMG_FOLDER+imgFileName);
```

В данном случае значение Constants.IMG_FOLDER = "image/". Попробуйте и отпишитесь.

Comment: Вообще я пытаюсь переделать вот это - http://kreotiv.ru/ImageViewFlipper.zip
В данный момент там идет сбор и показ картинок с SD-карты, а я хочу сделать чтобы показывались файлы из assets/images.
Буду признателен за любую помощь

Comment: Я Вам написал примерный код. Если у Вас есть заданные имена файлов по циклу подставляйте их в метод open(). Если у Вас неопределены имена файлов то вызовете метод assetManager.list("images/") и он вернет Вам список файлов.